# Need to know if my 1/0 wire will suffice

Tags: electrical, wiring, meter

I have a warehouse in my property that I want to work in during summer. The closest meter is 600 ft away and which is 200amp(240v) single phase. There are 3 wires in PVC to that meter but not connected. the wires are size 1/0 copper. I will be using 160 amps once connected and all my users run at 208V. Will I run into any kind of issues besides the fact that it will be very inefficient.

Comment: In some quick searching, (a) you're looking at around 10% voltage drop (but as you've noted, if you're running equipment that can handle 208, that *should* be OK) but (b) as far as I can tell, 1/0 is normally rated for only 150A. If that's true then this won't pass inspection. Key question: **Do you really expect to use 160A?**

Comment: So I live in a rural area and I am only going to be working there for two years so I will not be needing a city inspection since its temporary. I can work around 150 amps but I guess i wanted to know if I will actually get the 150 amps and if the wire will over heat or if breaker will hit.

Comment: The breaker will trip based on actual current. If you have 200A supply you would normally have 200A breaker with 80% (= 160A) as the maximum to be used continuously. Normally that means "use 200A rated wire" and while I'm not sure of the "right" answer, 1/0 definitely seems to be way too small *not even counting the long distance/voltage drop*. So the answer basically is "wire will overheat" long before breaker would trip.

Comment: So i will be using a 200 amp breaker but only drawing 150 amps.

Comment: My general understanding is that under such situations you need wire rated for 200A. Ignoring any distance issues, that would, I believe, normally be 3/0 copper. 1/0 copper would only get you 150A *total/max* and 120A *continuous*. See https://www.altestore.com/diy-solar-resources/maximum-ampacity-current-capacity-for-wire-and-cable/ for one such table. There are some variations (voltage drop = need more, certain exceptions for service entrance wire, which I don't think apply here, etc.). But I don't think 1/0 will do what you want.

Comment: If you use 150 amp rated wire but have a 200 amp breaker, you could be drawing near 200 amps for hours without tripping the breaker and burn up the wires. Safest to replace the 200 amp breaker with a 150 amp breaker.

Comment: @DoxyLover Problem then is if actually using 150A continuous then that won't trip the breaker but will violate code and not a good idea. The various wire size and other requirements take into account 80% max for continuous usage.

Comment: What size is the conduit in question?

Comment: also the 200a 240v meter has 2 hot legs if that makes any difference

Comment: conduit is 1/0 copper 3 of them in pvc pipe

Comment: @AlexManu he means, what is the trade size diameter of the PVC conduit? There are code rules around how many wires of a particular size can be put into a conduit of a certain size. If you tell us the conduit size, we can provide more guidance.

Comment: Conduit is 3 inch pvc

Comment: So if i put a 150amp breaker on meter and after 700 I draw about 130 Amps with 208V users will i be fine with the 1/0 wires? – 
 
and unfortunately, this was previous owners' idea to run 1/0 wire instead of the proper gauge wiring

Answer (score 2):

### *Maximum* wire capacity

We have to go strictly by Table 310.15(B)(16) and we use the 75C column - this says 150A.  If you are sure the equipment at both ends of the cable is listed for 90C terminations, then 170A is possible.

The largest breaker you can possibly use is 150A.   Even if it's 90C, there is no "rounding up to the next breaker size" on *service wire*.  So you're still 150A.

If your wire is aluminum, then it is 120A wire and you must breaker at 100A (no rounding up).  If the panel is 90C rated, then it's 135A wire and you can use a 125A breaker.

### Voltage drop, though.

In the US, you can run voltage drop as bad as you want (up to about 10%, after that you have ground wire sizing problems).   You can't plan to use more than 80% of wire ampacity.

- 150A --> 9.73% voltage drop
- 120A --> 7.78% drop
- 100A --> 6.49% drop
- 80A --> 5.19% drop
- 60A --> 3.89% drop
- 40A --> 2.6% drop

*That's terrible*.

The voltage is going to vary dynamically based on the current you are drawing *at that instant*, so don't use incandescents or cheap LEDs - they'll drive you bonkers with all their dimming.

Whose idea was this anyway?  Tear it all out and replace with 500 kcmil aluminum, I don't understand why the last guy didn't do that since it's about the same cost as the copper they did use.  People are dumb.

Or stick 2 transformers in there and kick it up to 480V or 600V for the long haul. That'll support gosh, almost 400A of power at 3.5% voltage drop plus maybe a percent on transformer losses.

### 240V single-phase vs 208V 3-phase

Generally, converting from one to the other is not feasible.  There are frobs to do it *if cost is no object*, but realistically, you will be giving to your customers exactly what the power company gives to you.  (minus all that voltage drop lol).

So either I'm confused here, or you are, or your customers are about to be disappointed.

And this is a big deal because 208V is 3-phase power, which certain motors require. They would need to change the motors on their machines.

Comment: So if i put a 150amp breaker on meter and after 700 I draw about 130 Amps with 208V users will i be fine with the 1/0 wires?

Comment: and unfortunately, this was previous owners' idea to run 1/0 wire instead of the proper gauge wiring

Comment: @AlexManu You can't plan to pull more than 80% of breaker trip, so 120A max.  And your 208V customers will be very angry with you because of the last section I wrote.  The real problem is this 120/208/240V stuff is all greek to you, and so you don't even know how to tell us what you have.  So we might be giving bad advice, but that doesn't mean it's going to magically work out in your favor.